# Can not read posted raw data in php from angularjs after enable HTTPS

Tags: php, angularjs, post, https

I am trying to make a post request from my angular js, as below

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.post(posturl, data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status + ' - ' + data);
        deferred.resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
        deferred.reject(msg);
    });
return deferred.promise;
```

and in my serve side php code for receiving raw data i am using following method

```
$post_data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
echo $post_data;
```

it was working perfectly when I am using http in my url.After I enable ssl in my server i can't read raw data from the post method.
How to resolve this?

Comment: **CORS** make sure that your backend is configured to allow requests from other domains to get it to work

Comment: @Evinn I am already configured the setup for CORS